# Providing server side data for Chart.js charts

Tags: javascript, c#, json, ajax, chart.js

I am trying to use a chart to represent some data from a database. So far I don't get the data from the db, I am having problems to just provide data via a Webmethod. I do always get a 404 error. I think there is something wrong in my url, but I am trying around for hours now and can't figure out how to solve it.

So here is my code:

My Index.asmx

```
namespace WebApplication1.Views.Home
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Index
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class Index : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public static List<string> getChartData()
        {
            var returnData = new List<string>();

            var chartLabel = new StringBuilder();
            var chartData = new StringBuilder();
            chartLabel.Append("[");
            chartData.Append("[");

            for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
            {


                chartLabel.Append(string.Format("'{0}',", new DateTime(2017, 7, i + 1).ToString()));
                chartData.Append(string.Format("{0},", (i * 2).ToString()));


            }

            chartData.Length--; //For removing ','  
            chartData.Append("]");
            chartLabel.Length--; //For removing ',' 
            chartLabel.Append("]");

            returnData.Add(chartLabel.ToString());
            returnData.Add(chartData.ToString());
            return returnData;
        }
    }
}
```

My Index.cshtml:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <canvas id="Chart" width="600" height="500"></canvas>
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
            var ctx = document.getElementById("Chart").getContext('2d');
           $.ajax({

                url: "Index.asmx/getChartData",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success:function(response)
                {
                    var chartLabel = eval(response.d[0]); //Labels
                    var chartData = eval(response.d[1]); //Data
                    var barData = {
                        labels: chartLabel,
                        datasets: [
                            {
                                label: 'July Sales',
                                fillColor: "rgba(225,225,225,0.2)",
                                strokeColor: "Blue",
                                pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                                pointStrokeColor: "Green",
                                pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                                pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                                data: chartData
                            }
                        ]
                    };
                    var skillsChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(barData);
                }

            });
        }
        );
</script>
```

I posted some more code, just because I have no idea where I made my mistake. Btw. both files are in the same directory.

This is the error I got: POST http://localhost:50337/Home/Index.asmx/getChartData 404 (Not Found)

Does anybody know how to fix it?

Comment: are u still looking for the answer? I had the exact problem and solved it, the difference is that mine was not in AJAX, I passed the chart to viewbag and received it at the View. Not sure if it is helpful for you!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning JSON data, try to write the data and also tell the browser about data by sending header information like:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-encoding", "utf8");
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(returnData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete 'static' keyword from method signature.